# Flash Actionscript 3 getCamera bizarre discrepancies and artefacts on video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, camera

We're using the Actionscript getCamera() API to access and stream the camera over RTMP. I'm not sure if anyone's come across this but depending on the browser we get some really strange effects on the camera input. In some cases the camera shows stretched and often in Firefox is shows central with a green bar on the right.

Is is possible to access the camera as cropped 16:9 on all browsers?

```
var videoWidth:Number = 427;
var videoHeight:Number = 240;

camera = Camera.getCamera();

// here are all the quality and performance settings
if (camera != null)
{
    camera.setMode(videoWidth, videoHeight, videoFrameRate, false); // false gives framerate priority apparently?? http://www.flash-communications.net/technotes/setMode/index.html
    camera.setQuality(videoBitrate, videoQuality);
    camera.setKeyFrameInterval(2);
}
else
{
    sourceVideoLabel.text = "No Camera Found\n";
}
```

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

Comment: i had similiar issues with some webcams that used the standard windows drivers, installing the "original" drivers downloaded from the manufacturers website usually dealt with the problem.

Comment: Interesting. In this case it's a Mac and we also see this across users on different platforms.

Comment: have you tried to use another resolution for the camera?

Comment: At ~480p this camera works in Chrome cropped but still shows with the green bar in firefox.